# Community Blogs Point Back to Blog Overflow Instead of SE.com/blogs

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, blog-overflow

I was reading the [Security.SE blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com/) and noticed it points back to [Blog Overflow](http://blogoverflow.com/), which is mostly dead as far as I can tell.

[image]

I checked the [SuperUser Community Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/) and noticed the same thing -

[image]

But going from the SE main page blog link, it heads to [SE.com/blogs](https://stackexchange.com/blogs).

Do the community blog links need to be updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had been implementing the new universal top bar to apply to the blogs this month (thanks to Anna Lear for implementing it yay~). In the process, the existing redirect that usually pointed `blogoverflow.com` over to `stackexchange.com/blogs` got somewhat disconnected for a couple days for some people due to our greatest nemesis and greatest ally, caching. It's since been fixed though, so now they all properly point to `stackexchange.com/blogs`.